# How to redirect stderr to a file in a cron job

Tags: sh, cron

I've got a cron job that is set up like this in my crontab:

```
*/1 * * * *  sudo /home/pi/coup/sensor.py  >> /home/pi/sensorLog.txt
```

It puts stdout into sensorLog.txt, and any stderr it generates gets put into an email.

I want both stdout and stderr to go into sensorLog.txt, so I added `1>&2` to the crontab, which is supposed to make stderr go into the same place as stdout.  It now looks like this:

```
*/1 * * * *  sudo /home/pi/coup/sensor.py  >> /home/pi/sensorLog.txt 1>&2
```

Now, both stdout and stderr both get put into an email, and nothing gets added to the file.  This is the opposite of what I am trying to accomplish.

How do I get both stdout and stderr to get redirected to the file?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It's the other way around:

```
*/1 * * * *  sudo /home/pi/coup/sensor.py  >> /home/pi/sensorLog.txt 2>&1
```

`2>&1` will redirect standard error (2) to standard output (1) which -in turn - was redirected to your log file. So, at the end, both stderr and stdout will go to your `sensorLog.txt`

Comment: Very important note which should be on the first page of google search if someone asks if there are no logs for cron: `2>&1` should be *after* redirecting to file. `... 2>&1 >>$log` doesn't work, use `... >>$log 2>&1` instead.