# Bash script executes Python manually, but not from cron

Tags: python, bash, cron

I've been trying to debug this for a while now and I feel like I've tried everything.

Code is slightly modified with *** for company reasons.

The following executes as expected when run from a session as my local user.

```
/var/www/****/***/run.sh path_to_my/script.py 2>&1 >> /var/www/****/***/test.log
```

Where run.sh is just a wrapper for running Python in a virtualenv:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

wd=$(dirname $0)

source ${wd}/virtualenv/bin/activate
python ${wd}/$1
```

I have placed a print statement inside of the Python main to show that it's being executed.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("I got in here...")
```

When running the command as my local user, the log will contain this printed statement. However, when run in cron as:

```
*/30 * * * * /var/www/****/***/run.sh path_to_my/script.py 2>&1 >> /var/www/****/***/test.log
```

I do not get any printed statement, nor do I receive any error output from the `2>&1`.

My permissions are 755 on both the .sh and .py scripts.

Everything works as expected except when run via cron.

Am I missing something? Does cron not use .bashrc for the crontab user?

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967093/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file-in-a-cron-job

Comment: I'm already redirecting stderr and stdout correctly. The question referenced didn't want the error to go to his log. In my case, I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure your local cronjob is running by putting the following in the crontab file and check to see if it get written out at /tmp/env.output after a minute or two

```
* * * * * env > /tmp/env.output
```

Second make sure the user running the crontab has permission to write to the /var/www/****/***/test.log file

Third try changing your script to

```
wd=$(dirname $0)
cd $wd
source activate
python ${wd}/$1
```

Edited: Anders was able to figure out the answer by himself by adding PYTHONPATH to the cron environment: `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${wd}"`

Comment: I do have the correct permissions for the log, since some other debugging text appears there. In this case, it's the Python that's not running. But your thoughts on `env` are helpful. Thank you.

Comment: That tip helped. PYTHONPATH was missing from the cron env. So I just made my script include `export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:${wd}"`. If you want to edit the answer to include this, I'll select it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Great that you've figured it out. Cheers!