# mysql database backup (cronjob) problem on ubuntu server

Tags: mysql, lampp

```
07 07 * * * user /opt/lampp/bin/mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD database | gzip > home/user/database.sql.gz
```

This script works on my dummy server (Ubuntu 18.04)

But it didn't work properly on my live server (Ubuntu Server 18.04), only produced database sql.gz (size : 20 bytes)

Comment: What's in that file? `gunzip -dc database.sql.gz`

Comment: it should be sql file from the database

but it returns as an empty file

Comment: 20 bytes is not empty. What does it say?

Comment: I'd try this without the `gzip` pipe and see what it says. There's an error of some kind for sure.

Comment: i tried gunzip, it contained sql file with 0 byte

Comment: I mean run that command independently to be sure it runs without errors, outside of cron. I'd also [capture STDERR to logs as well using `2>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34967093/how-to-redirect-stderr-to-a-file-in-a-cron-job) in case something's logged.

Comment: One thing I do is create a `cron/` directory and then create a complete script that runs the requested cron task in it. This allows you to test that it works independently, then schedule that `cron/backup-databases.sh` type task once confirmed, for example. These can be a lot easier to debug.

Comment: I find the solution. I have to re-write the command from terminal.. my old command will result : Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO). I tried to rewrite the command and it works normally. I wonder why

Comment: Sometimes you can find the bug but have no way to fix it, and other times you fix the bug without finding out why it was a problem.